# How to temporarily ignore/disable the the last cursor position of the editor XED?

Tags: configuration

How to ignore the the last cursor position of the editor XED by console?

It is known that something similar is possible in the following way:

XED, wipe the history for search:

```
gsettings reset org.x.editor.state.history-entry history-search-for
```

XED, wipe the replace history:

```
gsettings reset org.x.editor.state.history-entry history-replace-with
```

**Concretization, to avoid misunderstandings:**

The code we are looking for for the terminal, is to ignore the last cursor position, but not to disable it permanently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the `restore-cursor-position` with

```
gsettings set org.x.editor.preferences.editor restore-cursor-position false
```

This is permanent. If you want a temporary solution you can invoke `xed` with `+1` as option and the filename in question e.g.

```
xed +1 infile
```

that will open `infile` and position the cursor at the beginning of the file.
If you want to use it with a desktop launcher then something like this should work:

```
Exec=xed +1 %u
```

---

OK, another way would be to use an alternate `dconf` profile. You set the key to `false`, save the profile to another directory, and then set the key back to `true`. When you want to ignore the cursor position you load the saved profile, otherwise you run `xed` normally. Run

```
mkdir -p ~/.alt_xed/dconf/
gsettings reset org.x.editor.state.history-entry history-search-for
gsettings reset org.x.editor.state.history-entry history-replace-with
gsettings set org.x.editor.preferences.editor restore-cursor-position false
cp ~/.config/dconf/user ~/.alt_xed/dconf
gsettings set org.x.editor.preferences.editor restore-cursor-position true
```

If you then start your editor with the following command it will open any/all files with the cursor on the first line of the file:

```
XDG_CONFIG_HOME=~/.alt_xed xed
```

Comment: Thats works for me. THX

Comment: Its true, this special command need only run once. But If a people like me, do this + XED, wipe the history for search + XED, wipe the replace history, by one starter, it make sence for me.

Comment: THX for the hint. I updated the question.

Comment: If I run xed +1 myfile.txt, the cursor is on first position. But this change only the cutsor position for the file myfile.txt file on this moment. If i open one other .txt file, the old cursor posion will be remember again. So, thats dont delete the old cursor position.

Comment: @Alfred.37 -=:) OK, see my edit. This is my last edit, I give up - I don't know any other way to accomplish what you want.

Comment: The follow is good looking for me "gsettings set org.x.editor.preferences.editor restore-cursor-position false" THX